# Getting XPath of parent element using using text of child element

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

Given an XML structure like so:

```
<ul>
    <li role="treeitem" aria-level="1" aria-expanded="true">
        <span role="presentation"></span>
        <span>
            <span>Seasons</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false">
            <span role="presentation"></span>
            <span>
                <span>Winter months</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <ul></ul>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="true">
            <span role="presentation"></span>
            <span>
                <span>Spring months</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <ul >
            <li role="treeitem" aria-level="3" >
                <span>
                    <span>March</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <ul></ul>
            <li role="treeitem" aria-level="3">
                <span>
                    <span>April</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <ul></ul>
            <li role="treeitem" aria-level="3">
                <span>
                    <span>May</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <ul></ul>
        </ul>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false">
            <span role="presentation"></span>
            <span>
                <span>Summer months</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <ul></ul>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false">
            <span role="presentation"></span>
            <span>
                <span>Autumn months</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <ul></ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

where `<span role="presentation"></span>` are buttons, when clicked, open a tree branch. `aria-expanded = 'true'` means opened branch.

1. How could I get the path to the `li` element containing the text `'Winter months'` inside the child tags (save this in `String xpathToLi`)?
2. How could I get the value of `the aria-expanded` attribute from the found path `xpathToLi`?
3. If `aria-expanded = 'false'` inside the `xpathToLi` path, find into `xpathToLi` the element with `role = 'presentation'` and click on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using java.

1. How could I get the path to the li element containing the text 'Winter months' inside the child tags (save this in String xpathToLi)?

`WebElement xpathToLi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Winter months']/ancestor::li"));`

2. How could I get the value of the aria-expanded attribute from the found path xpathToLi?

`String ariaExpanded = xpathToLi.getAttribute("aria-expanded");`

3. If aria-expanded = 'false' inside the xpathToLi path, find into xpathToLi the element with role = 'presentation' and click on it.

`if(ariaExpanded.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
   xpathToLi.findElement(By.xpath("./span[@role='presentation']")).click();
 }`

Comment: Thank you! That helped! 
But instead 'parent' used 'ancestor'. Its difference from child in that it can be of any remoteness.
`//span[text()='Winter months']/ancestor::li`

Comment: Oh, yes it should be ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value of the attribute `aria-expanded` for the season of i.e. **Winter months** you can use the following solution:

- *Java* based *xpath* solution:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul//span[text()='Seasons']//following::ul[1]//span[text()='Winter months']//preceding::li[1]"))).getAttribute("aria-expanded"));
  ```
- *Python* based *xpath* solution:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul//span[text()='Seasons']//following::ul[1]//span[text()='Winter months']//preceding::li[1]"))).get_attribute("aria-expanded"))
  ```